# Can someone help explain the meaning here

Tags: japanese-to-english

> 国が成人をしっかり定義すれば、国には責任を持って成人ではない国民を教育し て成人にする義務が生じる。それが本当の義務教育だろう。

I have 'If the government were to sufficiently define what an adult is, it has the responsibility to turn uneducated adult citizens into educated adults. That is what true compulsory education is.' But it doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: Doesn't seem far off to me, but proof reading requests are off-topic on this site. Can you update the question to explain specifically which part is worrying you and why?

Comment: Yeah sure - I think it is the register of the sentence. The part that comes before this is him saying that the government hasn't properly defined adulthood and here I'm wondering whether to take a more snarky tone from the author.